# Will be changed all GCP setting force when if we change Google Workspace subscription?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Our Google Workspace domain has been use Google Workspace Enterprise Plus subscription for test purpose.
I want change the subscription to Google Workspace Business Standard.

If I change Google Workspace subscription,
Will be changed all setting force GCP Setting ?
For example, "User Auth Information of API&Service" or Domain Deligration (https://admin.google.com/ac/owl/domainwidedelegation)

Please advice to me.
Thanks.

Comment: I do not think the change will affect Google Cloud as the license type is applied to each user and does not change the user identity for Google Cloud. Since you have Enterprise, you also have enhanced support. Please contact them and post back their answer.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you for your answer. It has been very helpful. Have a nice day.